# Enum. Можно ли преобразовать строку в перечисление?

Tags: c#

Доброе утро. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то преобразовать строку в перечисление? Если да, то каким образом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Colors color = (Colors)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), "Green");

Comment: просто пример кода

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov, да.

Comment: Спасибо, отлично.